# NSDate to RFC 2822 Date format

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, nsurlrequest

Is there any efficient way to convert an NSDate to RFC 2822 Date format string ?
I want to use this string to create an NSURLRequest and set the value of "If-Modified-Since" header field.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try to use an `NSDateFormatter`

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; // maybe there exist a new-method now
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"; //RFC2822-Format
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:myDate];
```

Comment: I think you'd need to set the locale, too.

Comment: Extra line would be `dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US_POSIX"];`

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3,4,5

```
let rfcDateFormat = DateFormatter()
rfcDateFormat.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"
let dateString = rfcDateFormat.string(from: Date())
//today result: Mon, 06 Feb 2017 17:21:18 +0100
```