# Can't parse RFC822 date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm new in objective-c and i have my first problem with date formetter. I'm parsing a feed and i get the date for articles.

The format of this is : Tue, 31 Mar 2015 10:52:33 . I want to convert this sting into a date . I was trying multiples methods but always i get this:

```
NSDate *articleDate = [NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:dataArticol formatHint:DateFormatHintRFC3339];
NSDate *newData=[NSDate dateFromInternetDateTimeString:dataArticol formatHint:@"EEE , dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
```

Results :

```
2015-03-31 14:54:40.744 FluxRSS[6358:1052102] Could not parse RFC822 date: "Tue, 31 Mar 2015 10:52:33
            " Possible invalid format.
```

or if i do like :

```
 NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE , dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
    [formatter setLenient:YES];

    NSString* buggeredTime = [[dataArticol substringToIndex:26] stringByAppendingString:[dataArticol substringFromIndex:27]];

    NSDate* dueDate = [formatter dateFromString:buggeredTime];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"'Time Due: 'hh:mm a  MM/dd/yy"];
    NSString* dateString = [formatter stringFromDate:dueDate];
```

dueData is nil . Can anyone help me ,please?

Comment: The formatter you providing to can be told as wrong by merely looking at the date and the format you're using. A simple search would've get you what you want to do here like [NSDate to RFC 2822 Date format](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8636816/593709)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this code it's working..

```
 NSString *string=@"Tue, 31 Mar 2015 10:52:33";
 NSDateFormatter* formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MM yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
 NSDate *date=[formatter dateFromString:string];
```

Comment: yes . it's working, but if i put     NSString *string=dataArticol; the result is nil .

Comment: NSString *dataArticol= [[stories objectAtIndex: storyIndex] objectForKey: @"pubDate"];
  dataArticol = [dataArticol stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" +0000" withString:@""];
  this is how is set dataArticol

Comment: (lldb) po dataArticol  Tue, 31 Mar 2015 10:52:33

Comment: [formatter setDateFormat: @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"]; [formatter setDateFormat: @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss "]; chek both formate may work...